# How to make EditText view get focus and SoftKeyboard input in Presentation(Duel Screen)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

1. I am using Android `Presentation` to present different contents between the dual screens.
2. My Plan is to making the external display to present an `EditText` view, the Android device's main screen to present SoftKeyboard and get `EditText` view focus to make the input.

I try to use `EditText.requestFocus()` and `InputMethodManager` to open SoftKeyboard.

PS: Do not tell me to use `onKeyDown` listener and `TextView.append()`

```
public class MainPresentationFragment extends PresentationFragment {
private EditText textView3;

public MainPresentationFragment() {}

public static MainPresentationFragment newInstance(Context context, Display display){
    MainPresentationFragment mainPresentationFragment = new MainPresentationFragment();
    mainPresentationFragment.setDisplay(context, display);
    return mainPresentationFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView3 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        textView3.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }
return rootView;
}
```

SoftKeyboard can present on the main screen, but `EditText` cannot get input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SoftKeyboard can present on the main screen, but EditText cannot get input.

Correct. `Presentation` is output-only. There is no input.

> My Plan is to making the external display to present an EditText view, the Android device's main screen to present SoftKeyboard and get EditText view focus to make the input.

You should be able to get something like that if:

- You put the real `EditText` on the device's main screen
- You mirror the `EditText` to the `Presentation`, such as via [my `MirroringFrameLayout` and `Mirror` classes](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts#usage-mirroing)

Alternatively, you would need to use something like a `TextWatcher` on the main screen's `EditText` and duplicate the entered text onto the `Presentation`'s `EditText`. This would be akin to the "onKeyDown listener and TextView.append()" approach that you seem to dislike.

Comment: I knew your `MirroringFrameLayout`, which is Awesome I love it. But this time I need to do what I said. I did some research about `Presentation` I found In 'Presentation' all views keep original attribute, their listener is working, so I made a mouse course on external display to simulate click event, which works! `TextView` can be got click but I do not know why `requestFocus()` is not working